# Duplicate data with multiple instance of microservice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, microservices

I have a problem with duplicate data.
I have a client that call an API multiple time to fill some grid.
The API instance a service that check if the data exists and if not it create all the data.
The problem is that when the method that creates the data is heavy and takes a long time. So 2 methods run at the same time and both saves the data creating duplicates
Can I queue the API call and exucte them one at time?
Or there is another way to achieve that?
Here the code of the API

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/v1/Combinations")]
public class CombinationsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommonService _CommonService;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CombinationsController(ICommonService CommonService,
        ILogger<CombinationsController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _CommonService = CommonService;
    } 

    [HttpPost("GenerateCombinationsByAttributes",Name ="GenerateCombinationsByAttributes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateCombinationsByAttributes([FromBody] List<Guid> attributeIds)
    {
        if (attributeIds == null || attributeIds.Count == 0 || attributeIds.Contains(Guid.Empty))
            return BadRequest();

        var ret = await _CommonService.GenerateCombinationByAttributesList(attributeIds);

        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Comment: put `lock` (or `MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)`- not sure if .net core supports it) inside `GenerateCombinationByAttributesList` implementation ... or use transaction in `GenerateCombinationByAttributesList` ... it depends

Comment: @Selvin i think the lock will be local and valid only inside the instance of the microservice so every instance will have it's own lock. The instance of the microservice is transient 
`services.AddTransient<ICommonService, CommonService>();`

Comment: ok I don't know what `services` is ... but most IoC which I know is using single instance of service ... but even if you still can do lock over `static object mylock = new object();`

Comment: @Selvin services is `IServiceCollection services` of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and also won't `lock` inside of `async Task` cause some sort of problems? Anyway i'm gonna try to put a lock

Comment: what about db transaction? (of course if you are using db inside GenerateCombinationByAttributesList)

Comment: what about queuing jobs in hangfire ?

Comment: @Selvin i'm using a repository pattern son I have a UoW with all the repository. Also I cannot use lock because i cannot await inside the body of a lock

Comment: @PMerlet never used it, I will have a look

Comment: I think i have solved with a `static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);`

Inside the service before everything i call `await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();` and in the `finally` block i call `semaphoreSlim.Release();`

Comment: Is there anything unique on the record? If there's any column where the value cannot be repeated, then this becomes very simple. You simply catch the DB exception thrown for violating the unique constraint, and then then do a select/update.

Comment: @ChrisPratt It has a guid to identify it, but the other values can appear multiple times, because an item can appear in multiple combination. But a combination must be unique, also the Guid that are generated never violate the unique constraint so it is not possible to find if a combination already exist if the 2 task run in parallel

Comment: Combo unique should work well enough. You'd just need to add a unique constraint for the multiple columns that must be unique together.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I create a combination with child elements combinatio item, the combination itself hasnt anything unique but the list of the child must be unique.
The child have a guid to defgine the typer and a value, but that can appear multiple time in the child tables because an element can be in multiple combination. The unique uniqueness is the total of the children for a specific combination

Comment: That's not really going to work then.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to selved it with a simple semaphore
I've declared a

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

inside the microservice class
and then

```
 public async Task<Result> GenerateCombinationByAttributesList(List<Guid> attributeIds)
    {
        var result = new Result();
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            DoHeavyStuffHere();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            result.SetError(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why not `ManualResetEventSlim` ?